# Disable Redhat Openshift Service on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, devops, redhat-containers

I've enabled RedHat OpenShift Service on AWS but can't find an intuitive way to disable it.

Wondering if anyone has idea and also if the ROSA CLI is the only way to do it?

[image]

Also, if someone can help understand the pricing model below on AWS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cost or penalty for leaving the ROSA service enabled. I'm not aware that it's actually *possible* to disable the service, but if you don't need it, you won't be charged anything.

The cost structure is basically a $0.03/hour cost for each ROSA cluster that you run. There is also *either* an hourly cost of $0.171/hour for each 4vCPU that you're running **or** an annual cost of $1000/year for each 4vCPU that you're running. This is for the OpenShift management/subscription costs, you would still pay the EC2 costs separately.

For example, if you're running 2 clusters, with 2 m5.4xlarge worker nodes each, you would be looking at an estimated hourly cost of $2.796 from the ROSA service. There are [additional AWS resources](https://docs.openshift.com/rosa/rosa_planning/rosa-sts-aws-prereqs.html#rosa-aws-policy-provisioned_rosa-sts-aws-prereqs) that are utilized that you would pay for in *addition* to the ROSA service costs.

*Estimated hourly cost example:*

```
2x clusters @ $0.03/hr each:  $0.06/hr
4x m5.4xlarge (16vCPU each) nodes total across both clusters = 
    64vCPU total / 4vCPU = 
    16x 4vCPU @ $0.171/hr each = $2.736/hr

$2.736 + $0.06 = $2.796/hr total
```

See https://aws.amazon.com/rosa/pricing/ for additional pricing examples